# How to number of words with length greater than three in a given file and recording

Tags: java

I am trying to search a given text doc. for words with a length of 3 or greater and then record the number of each and display on screen. I'll put what I have thus far below. I'm running into a problem with finding the max length of words in the doc. so I know when to stop recording. Also, I'm having trouble with maybe streamlining the program instead of running so many if\if-else statements.

Regards!

```
public static int WordLengthCount() throws FileNotFoundException {
File file = new File("document.txt");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
    int count5 = 0;
    int count6 = 0;
    while (keyboard.hasNext()) {
        if (keyboard.next().length() == 5) {
            count5++;
        }
        else if (keyboard.next().length() == 6) {
            count6++;
}

}
return count5;
```

Comment: 2 if statements isn't very many; as you have 3 distinct conditions to distinguish between (length=5, length=6, length is neither 5 nor 6), hard to reduce it further.  Then again, you don't see to use `count6` so it isn't clear why you have it.

Comment: Maybe use an int array and for any length > 2 do `arr[word.length() - 3]++`, then you would have the count for each word where `arr[0]` is the count of words with 3 letters, `arr[1]` is 4 chars etc.

Comment: I would have to add if statements equal to the max length of words in the document. i.e. count6, count7… after finding the longest word by reading through the document or accounting for a max possible length manually.

Comment: generally when you find yourself making variables like `count1`, `count2`, `count3`... you need to start looking into some form of iterable collection.

Comment: I've settled upon a Map. Might you know how I can access data at a specific place (position, key?) in the Map. ie at 1 of the map, representing words of length three, the number of words of that length is 12000. How do I access that number so I can find the frequency of 3 letter words?

Comment: Check my answer. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `.next()` twice in the `while` loop, so you are actually reading 2 Strings, not one, on each iteration. You need to store the String returned by `.next()` in a variable and check the length of that string. Your first `if` statement is reading the next String in the file and checking its length and the `else if` is reading in the String after the previous String and checking its length.

```
while (keyboard.hasNext()) {
    final String next = keyboard.next();
    if (next.length() == 5) {
        count5++;
    } else if (next.length() == 6) {
        count6++;
    }
}
```

If the number of characters you need to count are dynamic, you can use a `Map`.

```
final Map<Integer, Integer> charCount = new HashMap<>();
//the key for this map is the length of the word and the value is the number of times a word with that length was found
while (keyboard.hasNext()) {
    final String next = keyboard.next();
    final Integer len = next.length();
    if(charCount.has(len){
       charCount.put(len, charCount.get(len)+1);
    } else {
       charCount.put(len, 1);
    }
}
//print the values
for(final Integer key: charCount.keySet()){
    System.out.println("A word with length " + key + " characters was found "+ charCount.get(key) + " times.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 or higher then this solution could help you.

- Use Map for holding counters (values) for each length (keys)
- For any word with length >= 3 I use `merge` to create/update counter for a length
- Use a stream to sort the keys and print length & count in ascending order
- Use stream and `max` method to find largest value for the keys, that is the longest word

---

```
public static int wordLengthCount() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("document.txt");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
    Map<Integer, Integer> wordLengths = new HashMap<>();
    while (keyboard.hasNext()) {
        String word = keyboard.next();
        Integer length = word.length();
        if (length >= 3) {
            wordLengths.merge(length, 1, Integer::sum);
        }
    }
    keyboard.close();

    wordLengths.keySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder()).forEach(key -> {
        System.out.printf("Word length %d occured %d times\n", key, wordLengths.get(key));
    });

    int maxLength = wordLengths.keySet().stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
    return maxLength;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Max length = " + wordLengthCount());
}
```